# Component Recommendation for Building an "Ubuntu Computer" from scratch

Tags: compiling

Well, good afternoon all!

Before posting this inquiry I did look through the list of "hits" given by the search and found only 1 posting with my specific question: is there a list of Ubuntu compatible PC components out there somewhere?  The one posting, that asked the question I have, a listing of Ubuntu compatible components to build a PC from scratch, had some feedback.  One of the lists provided is no longer available, one has been hacked and leads to a healthcare website and the last appears to be for looking through a Linux based machine after the fact (post-build).  What I would like to see is a list of parts that have a track record of compatibility (in life nothing is guaranteed) with Ubuntu.

I am currently in the process of getting a Macbook Air running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and it has been "interesting".  The desktop I am running Windoz 10 on cannot run Ubuntu because of the Intel RAID being used (it's a low end HP Pavilion) so I am toying with the idea of rolling my own, so to speak, but don't want to put it together, start it up, and find out I invested in one or more problematic components.  I have built PC's in the past but always with Windoz in mind, but I is dun growed up now!

Thanks in advance for any info you can provide...
...Cheers!

Comment: The Mac was an older (2017-18) model and was no longer being used for anything "important", seemed like a good place to play with Ubuntu without mucking up the primary system.I would rather not rely on a manufacturer/retailer based on their generous return policy plus it would give me the opportunity to build a system again.  I'm not looking to build a super-duper system, just something reasonably secure that doesn't have anything to do with either MS or Apple (since they both seem to have agendas I will not support).

Answer (score 0):

Start at https://certification.ubuntu.com/

You will need to dig through various systems to find their components. The information is there, but it's not in the format you are asking for.

Many non-certified components work very will with Linux, too. And a few don't.